# i wrote the script scp/sftp with password, passphrase and private key , it work with winscp but not from my linux shell

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/scp  -i "/pkg/scripts/myppk.ppk"  -P 11111    lulumea@11.11.11.11:/OUT/mycsc.csv  /manpkg
expect {
expect "*phrase*" {
    send "mypassphrase\r"
    
}
expect "*sword.*" {
    send "mypassword\r"
}
}
interact
```

Comment: can you describe more preceisely "not work" ?

Comment: Does `scp` understand Putty's `.ppk` files? whenever I've used it in the past, it was necessary to convert the .ppk file to an OpenSSH key (using PuTTYgen's `export` feature for example)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually tell us what goes wrong, what errors you get or anything, so this is a guess. I bet the problem is the fact that you are sending the passphrase and password with an `\r` at the end for some reason. That... doesn't really make sense for any modern system. Only old Macs used to have `\r` as the end of line character, modern Macs and all other *nix systems use `\n` and Windows uses`\r\n`.

To have this work on *nix systems, you will need to replace the `\r` with an `\n`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/scp  -i "/pkg/scripts/myppk.ppk"  -P 11111    lulumea@11.11.11.11:/OUT/mycsc.csv  /manpkg
expect {
expect "*phrase*" {
    send "mypassphrase\n"
    
}
expect "*sword.*" {
    send "mypassword\n"
}
}
interact
```

If that doesn't solve your issue, please edit your question and explain what is actually happening when you run it.